# Print the name of a pressed key in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Does AS3 have a way to output the physical name of a key that has been pressed? (ie. "You pressed: Left Arrow")

The obvious solution is to convert the character code to a string, but this only works for things like the alphanumeric keys. Ctrl, Alt, etc have special cases, but this still doesn't help for things like the arrow keys or the F-keys.

Another possibly naive option is to have a Key, Value pair for all the keycodes and their names. It should be almost trivial (if tedious) to code this myself, but since AIR already has things like

```
KEYNAME_LEFTARROW : String = "Left"
```

I was wondering if this ability is already built in somewhere without having to keep my own collection of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, AS3 does not have a way to output the special keys that you have mentioned but with a simple Google search you can find a class to do it for you.  Or you will have to do something like you mentioned, where you associate a string with the key code.  It is a hassle, but there are plenty of classes located online where people have already done this but there honestly isn't that many keys that Flash allows you to be used in the browser anyways so it doesn't take much time to do.

Comment: Thanks, it only took a few minutes. I just didn't want to re-write something that might have been built in.